# SQL Server endpoint configuration

Tags: sql-server, endpoints

How does one check that a SQL Server end point has been set to listen to all IP addresses?

i.e

I need to run the command below however I need to backup the current values. 
I am only able to find create or alter commands but nothing on how to list the current properties of an SQL end point

```
ALTER ENDPOINT [tester-hadr] 
    AS TCP (LISTENER_IP = ALL)
GO
```

Comment: There are some sys catalog views:  `sys.endpoints` and `sys.tcp_endpoints` for example. Ref: [Endpoints Catalog Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/endpoints-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)